# What is the right approach to research when goal is not to publish in top conferences?

Tags: research-process

I am theoretical computer scientist. I am currently working in a local university in south  asian country. I have tried my best in the past to publish the research in good venue but have been failed. Now I am okay or fine with publishing in low tier conferences.

I have one doubt about my approach. I read top conference papers like STOC,FOCS,SODA and understand them if they seems interesting to me. Then I try to rephrase a research mentioned in the paper. After working on that question results in a paper.

The problem with approach is it takes quite a time to read and understand papers from top conferences as they are lengthy and nontrivial. This some time takes 4-5 months and total time for one paper is around 6-7 months. Many times it seems after reading these papers that there is no scope of improvement. In that case to me it appears that I should have read a paper of a conference which is not top tier. Lets say paper X is published in tier 2 conference then in most of the cases the reason it has been published in tier 2 is incomplete solution (partial solution to a problem).

Now the question is How to research if my goal is to publish and not to bother about ranking of the conference in efficient manner (time and energy)

Comment: What questions are *you* interested in?  What do *you* want to find out more about?  I have way more problems I would like to solve than I have time to work on them, and I rarely read a paper without having some reason to believe that it contains information relevant to a problem I am already interested in solving.  I find it hard to imagine someone with a PhD who is not in that position.

Comment: You can read papers faster with practice.

Comment: What did you write your PhD dissertation on?  Why aren't you working on extending the results of your PhD?  Why are you reading random SODA papers instead of the one that's most related to what you already know?

Comment: @Alexander Woo Algorithmic questions related to graphs.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist Agree

Comment: What does your advisor say? I would never have been able to write my first paper without my advisor who had an idea of "how to write a paper for the X conference".

Comment: @lighthouse keeper I am done with my PhD and graduated.

Comment: @Coreman Did you not publish anything during your PhD? I think then you might have been set up for failure :/

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing, but I think you haven't sufficiently specialized.

Most theoretical computer scientists are not specializing in something as broad as graph algorithms.  They are specializing in something extremely narrow, say specifically in list coloring algorithms, or specifically in adaptations of Lenstra's integer programming algorithm.  Your aim should be to specialize in something so narrow that you are the world expert in that very narrow area.

Don't try to understand anyone else's work completely; you only need to understand it well enough to see how it contributes to your work.  Because you have focused on your area well enough, you should be able to read (the relevant parts of) papers much faster.

The danger in doing this is that you end up producing work that no one else is interested in, but, as long as it remains legitimate research, it should be publishable in lower-tier conferences.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't want to tell my exact topic of my PhD. That's why I am not writing it completely.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you are working alone. That makes everything harder. I suggest that you try to form some collaborative group of people with similar interests. It doesn't need to be local, but you probably need a way to meet them also. That is what makes CS conferences so powerful; you get to meet and interact with other researchers.

This is actually easier now, with the internet, than it used to be. You can "zoom" about, so to speak without physical travel.

If your university permits and can provide funds, you might invite someone to visit who has similar interests. Or you can possibly visit another university for a week or two in order to work with someone.

Your old PhD advisor might be able to put you in contact with people.

Once you get a few people, even two or three, thinking along similar lines, the ideas may flow. But just reading and trying to then extend the work of others is fundamentally a slow process as you have seen. If the research area is active, then others (who are probably collaborating) are going to beat you.

Strength in numbers. Perhaps you will get into those conferences in time.